# Can't get DIV's equal in height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

As simple as it normally is, for some reason I can't seem to get the same column heights for three divs in a row without using `min-height` or jQuery.

I am trying to use `display:table` on the main div and `display:table-cell` on the child's. I have no clue what is going wrong. I also tried other solutions, e.g. `display:inline-block;` and `:before { content:"" };` as suggested in several other posts.

```
<div class="row">

<!-- 3 times in a row, other two blocks cut here for overview on SO -->

<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-4">
<div class="highlighted-contentblock">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="contentheader">
            <div class="sequence">
                1
            </div>
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </h2>
        </div>
        Lorem
    </a>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqr1b17/2/)

```
 .large-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
display:table; }


.highlighted-contentblock
{
    background:gray;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqr1b17/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

It looks like the original issue was trying to apply table-cell to the class highlighted-contentblock instead of columns. The columns class is the first child of your row class and table-cell should be applied there.

## Columns

You had display table on your columns (applied on the highlighted-contentblock class). I replaced that with table-cell applied to the columns class.

## Spacing

Float removes margin so I removed that and used border spacing on your table instead.

## Support

This works but not in IE 7. [CSS tricks has more info](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).

### Click run code snippet below to see it in action.

```css
/* Foundation replacement */
.row {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    max-width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:0.9375rem;
 }

.columns {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:table-cell;
    background:gray;
 }

.large-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-4">
    
<div class="highlighted-contentblock">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="contentheader">
            <div class="sequence">
                1
            </div>
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </h2>
        </div>
        Lorem
    </a>
</div>
    
</div>

<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-4" data-equalizer-watch="">
    
<div class="highlighted-contentblock">
    <a target="_blank" href=#>
        <div class="contentheader">
            <div class="sequence">
                X
            </div>
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum <br/> Lorem ipsum
            </h2>
        </div>
        Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-4" data-equalizer-watch="">
    
<div class="highlighted-contentblock">
    <a target="_blank" href=#>
        <div class="contentheader">
            <div class="sequence">
                3
            </div>
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum
            </h2>
        </div>
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is a bit messy to be honest. You want to be following this simple structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Content</div>
    <div class="col">Content</div>
    <div class="col">Content</div>
</div>
```

And then set a few simple CSS rules

```
.row {
    display: table;
}
.col {
    display:table-cell;
    width:33.33%;
}
```

The crucial thing here is setting the width of your table cells.

I have updated your fiddle to show this in action 
http://jsfiddle.net/eaqr1b17/5/

Comment: Yep it is.. It's the output of Sitecore. That's where it is a mess. I only have access to the FE unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 1):

With floated element, the table/table-cell rendering is a bit difficult to render correctly...

If you can, remove the float element, and display them side by side with the table-cell.

The second problem of your code is that you have a background on the child element of the one that is rendered with a table-cell. So the height of all .column elements will be the same, but you won't see it with the background-color, because that property is setted to the child element that has its own height...

Here is an update of your fiddle without the float and with a border to show you that the height is correctly setted, but you don't see it because your bg-color is not applied to the right element :

**http://jsfiddle.net/eaqr1b17/6/**

```
/* Foundation replacement */
.row
{
    padding-bottom:10px;  
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
.columns {
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.large-4 {
    width: 33.33333%; 
}
.highlighted-contentblock
{
    background:lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your markup you have do to it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rvos3hx3/

```
/* Foundation replacement */
 .row {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    max-width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
}
.columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:gray;
    display:table-cell;
}
.large-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
    Lorem    
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
    Lorem impsum more text
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the css:

```
.wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell{
    width: 33.33%;
    display: table-cell; 
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

if you want to see it running click here
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Harryaars/fsqmbo2n/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nrnLbv14/

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">content 1</div>
        <div class="column">content 2</div>
        <div class="column">content 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    display:table;
    /* just styling to show it works */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.row .column {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 33.33%; // If you want all 3 columns equal width
}
```